# Base64 encoding variations? I have base64 encoded data not decoding properly

Tags: base64

I have some data coming through a web service that was described as base64 encoded.

Example: `AgAOAAAAQQEA3AcKDhIyCNwHCg4SMgyYIzSWoACP1T2TRRw1MTExMDUwMTE2ICAAAAAAAAAAAAAA3AAjU1QsKzAyMjEuMGxiDQo=`

However, attempting to decode this isn't coming up with the results I would have expected:

```
>>> base64.b64decode('AgAOAAAAQQEA3AcKDhIyCNwHCg4SMgyYIzSWoACP1T2TRRw1MTExMDUwMTE2ICAAAAAAAAAAAAAA3AAjU1QsKzAyMjEuMGxiDQo=')
'\x02\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00A\x01\x00\xdc\x07\n\x0e\x122\x08\xdc\x07\n\x0e\x122\x0c\x98#4\x96\xa0\x00\x8f\xd5=\x93E\x1c5111050116  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xdc\x00#ST,+0221.0lb\r\n'
```

It looks like the end of the decoded string is kinda-sorta along the lines of what I'm looking for. It should theoretically be transformable to something resembling `MT=2012-10-14 18:50:08, TT=2012-10-14 18:50:12, BT=00:A0:96:34:23:98, SN=5111050116  , BL=6.30V, S/H=4/3, Weight=221.0lb(100.24kg)` but I can't figure out what's going on with the encoding here.

Comment: Is this a mysql binlog dump you're trying to recover?

Comment: Nope, POSTed device readings from a Qualcomm device

Comment: Updated my answer with everything I can tell you right now, I don't know how to decode BL or S/H and without information about what those fields might represent I have absolutely no way of guessing how they are encoded, hope they're not crucial or that you can come up with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have so far, I probably need more info to decode everything but here it goes:

```
>>> t = base64.b64decode('AgAOAAAAQQEA3AcKDhIyCNwHCg4SMgyYIzSWoACP1T2TRRw1MTExMDUwMTE2ICAAAAAAAAAAAAAA3AAjU1QsKzAyMjEuMGxiDQo=')
```

Datetime fields MT and TT in order are:

```
>>> print int(t[9:11][::-1].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[11].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[12].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[13].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[14].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[15].encode("hex"), 16)
2012 10 14 18 50 8

>>> print int(t[16:18][::-1].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[18].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[19].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[20].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[21].encode("hex"), 16), int(t[22].encode("hex"), 16)
2012 10 14 18 50 12
```

BT is, you just have to add the ':' each two letters :

```
>>> t[23:29][::-1].encode("hex")
'00a096342398'
```

SN is:

```
>>> t[35:47]
'5111050116  '
```

Weight is:

```
>>> t[63:72]
'+0221.0lb'
```

Sorry but I don't have any idea at the moment how the rest are stored, and since I don't know what the range on those might be either I really have no way of decoding the rest, let me know if you can disclose a bit more information about what those fields should store.